# Satisfying condition for another column

Tags: r

I've read through multiple questions and not found some code that's worked so appreciate your help. This is a refinement of an earlier question and although I can do this in Excel, I am trying to get my R up to speed.

I have some sales data which is giving me a headache:

```
date    sales
14/11   39
14/11   3.2
14/11   13
14/11   8.3
14/11   5
14/11   5.6
14/11   79
14/11   35
14/11   24
14/11   8.1
14/11   21
14/11   40
14/11   50
14/11   82
15/11   8.3
15/11   7.2
15/11   63
15/11   31
15/11   35
15/11   2.1
15/11   31
15/11   11
15/11   3.8
15/11   29
15/11   NA
```

I've been shown how to group the dates and find the bottom three performers but I want to keep the rest of the data visible.

I would like to see another column with a ranking of the bottom three sales reports saying TRUE and if not, FALSE

I've tried:

```
if(data$sales == group_by(data$date)%>%top_n(n=-3, wt=sales)) {
data$top <- T
} else {
dat$top <- F
}
```

And all I get is:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

This isn't the first attempt either - I've tried for loops, if | else, match, %in% and really struggling but don't want to dump a ream of bad code here.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(bottom3 = ifelse(rank(sales) <= 3, TRUE, FALSE))

# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups:   date [2]
   date  sales bottom3
   <chr> <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 15/11  2.10 T      
 2 14/11  3.20 T      
 3 15/11  3.80 T      
 4 14/11  5.00 T      
 5 14/11  5.60 T      
 6 15/11  7.20 T      
 7 14/11  8.10 F      
 8 14/11  8.30 F      
 9 15/11  8.30 F      
10 15/11 11.0  F      
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Comment: I've cleaned up the data and changed all the sales to as.numeric(as.character)) but still all I get in the third column is F all the way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  arrange(date, sales) %>%
  mutate(bottom3_performer = row_number() <=3)
```

Output is:

```
    date sales bottom3_performer
1  14/11   3.2              TRUE
2  14/11   5.0              TRUE
3  14/11   5.6              TRUE
4  14/11   8.1             FALSE
5  14/11   8.3             FALSE
6  14/11  13.0             FALSE
7  14/11  21.0             FALSE
...
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", 
"14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", 
"14/11", "14/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", 
"15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11"), sales = c(39, 
3.2, 13, 8.3, 5, 5.6, 79, 35, 24, 8.1, 21, 40, 50, 82, 8.3, 7.2, 
63, 31, 35, 2.1, 31, 11, 3.8, 29, NA)), .Names = c("date", "sales"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Another set of sample data & o/p:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", 
"14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", "14/11", 
"14/11", "14/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", 
"15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11", "15/11"), sales = c(39, 
3.2, 13, 8.3, 5, 5.6, 79, 35, 24, 8.1, 21, 40, 50, 82, 8.3, 7.2, 
63, 31, 35, 2.1, 31, 11, 3.8, 29, NA), id = 1:25, name = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y")), .Names = c("date", 
"sales", "id", "name"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")

    date sales    id  name bottom3_performer
 1 14/11   3.2     2     b              TRUE
 2 14/11   5.0     5     e              TRUE
 3 14/11   5.6     6     f              TRUE
 4 14/11   8.1    10     j             FALSE
 5 14/11   8.3     4     d             FALSE
 6 14/11  13.0     3     c             FALSE
 7 14/11  21.0    11     k             FALSE
...
```

Comment: With the small amount of data, this works, but when I have multiple other columns (salesperson's name, id #, etc) it seems to find a different answer to the bottom 3. I've gone through and tried to remove all --- values as NA but not sure what else to do?

Comment: Tried it with and without the middle row as well!

Comment: not sure if I get the followup question. But I just tried above code on another set of sample data (added few more columns - `id` & `name`) and it's working as you have expected in your post (refer the updated answer!).

Comment: It looks like there might be some different classifications in the columns so will do a clean and get back to you!

Comment: Sorry, even after cleaning the data, now all I get is FALSE in the column.

Comment: Can you update your original post with sample data from your cleaned data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Will do when I can - it's not the real data, but a scrape of the structure. I'm also working through a number of variations of the approaches offered as much to learn but it's a combination of frustrating and educational!